# Using multiple '*' patterns when loading into BigQuery won't work

Tags: google-bigquery

We're trying to use a glob pattern when loading into BigQuery, for example:

```
gs://<bucket_name>/Network*Impressions_12345_20150201*
```

We have both "..NetworkImpressions_.." and "..Network**Backfill**Impressions_.." in our bucket, so we use the first '*' to scoop up both types of files. But BQ borks with:

> "Not found: URI
>   gs://backup-gdfp-7415/Network*Impressions_232503_20150101_20*"

The files definitely exist. If we remove the first '*' it works fine (and when we explicitly specify both types).

Here's a job id for a failed load job where we are trying to use the pattern: job_LXNGEAeWsaU9HyFgcCCJMHu8YtY

I would have thought this should be possible with BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for load job configuration [sourceUris parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.sourceUris):

[Required] The fully-qualified URIs that point to your data in Google Cloud Storage. **Wildcard names are only supported when they appear at the end of the URI.**

Comment: Face palm! Missed it in the doco's. Thanks! Any chance of adding this as a feature request?

Comment: One clarification this hasn't been updated in the docs, but wildcards within the URI should work, just not multiple URIS. So gs://foo/bar*.csv should worl.