# Move an entire bucket from google cloud storage to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

From Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery transfers documentation which I have been reading, I can see how I can load data files one-by-one.

Is there a way to add an entire bucket into BigQuery?

The folders and files are logs for an organization. We're looking to create visualizations based off those using them. But first we need to get the bucket data into BigQuery...

Bucket Structure is as follows:

> BucketName -> LogDate (ex. 20180623) -> all individual logs

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: @Tamir_Klein thanks for the edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple '\*' patterns when loading into BigQuery won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756065/using-multiple-patterns-when-loading-into-bigquery-wont-work)

Comment: ..and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303333/how-to-load-multiple-files-same-schema-into-a-table-in-bigquery

Comment: ..and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074038/how-can-we-load-files-under-folder-into-big-query-from-google-storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard in your load process to achieve what you are looking to do as described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#load-wildcards)

The relevant part of the documentation is this:

> For example, if you have two files named fed-sample000001.csv and fed-sample000002.csv, the bucket URI would be **gs://mybucket/fed-sample***. This wildcard URI can then be used in the console, the classic UI, the CLI, or the API.

Comment: so if I have .log.gz files in the folder path cited above, and all the file names are like: 20190329U_20190329T1703651Z_465u2f8.log.gz    how would the cloud storage URI look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can `load` those nested logs iteratively. For instance, if your logs are in CSV format, having three fields in them:

```
gsutil ls gs://mybucket/* | grep '.csv' | xargs -I {} bq --location=US load --source_format=CSV mydataset.mytable {} field_a:type_field_a, field_b:type_field_b, field_c:type_field_c
```

Here, note how the schema is specified inline in the format of `field_[x]:type_field_[x]` where type can be any column type supported by BQ.

Comment: Hi! How this would change if you want to put the each csv file in different tables and name the tables with the 6 initial characters of each csv file?